# Focussing on burning calories and six pack abs and an overall change

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, workout-routines, training

My native language is not English so I apologize if some terms are not correctly stated.

I regularly go to the gym twice a week. What I do there is 10 minutes crosstrainer, leg press, chest press, stiff arm lat pulldowns, cable curls, pushdowns and shoulder press. I do this 3 sets with 15 repeats. The day after my gym day ( I make a break of 1 day between each gym day ) I execute [this abs training](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9oAbP7LHT9Q). I trained for 4 month now and got a feeling for the gym and the exercises. Now what I aim to change. I want to burn more calories and get my sixpack abs on :D ( my height is 1.68m or 5'6 and I weigh 67kilograms at the moment ). What can I change to make those changes? The reason Why I posted the other stuff that isn't abs related, because I really don't know much about training plans and if somebody would suggest some change or some additions I would be open to it! This is just a training plan from some app I got from the app store :)

Answer (score 2):

Your ability to obtain “six pack abs” is going to be limited by a few factors, some in your control, and, others you can’t control.

- First, set a realistic goal.  Don’t aspire to the abs you see in the
  fitness magazines.  We all have different musculature, so, your abs
  will probably look completely different from those in the magazines
  when stripped of fat.  Genetics will play a part in what abs will
  look like.
- Consistency – the key to any fitness program is consistency.  Plan on
  working on abs for a long time.  Great abs typically take a while to
  achieve.
- Exercise selection – There’s no one perfect ab exercise.  If there were, we’d all have great abs.  Experiment with different ab exercises that target the [muscles that make up great
  abs](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/abdominal-encyclopedia-core-anatomy-and-effective-training.html):
  Rectus Abdominis, External Obliques, Internal Obliques, and the
  Transverse Abdominis.  Most people neglect training one or more of
  these muscles.
- Clean diet – Try to follow a clean, low fat diet. That does not mean
  you need to eat strictly all the time.  Pick one day a week to cheat
  and you’ll eat cleanly 86% of the time.

Lastly, since you can’t spot reduce for great abs, try to follow an overall fitness program that encompasses work for **all** major body parts.  The key is to try to continuously burn calories while building muscle and maintaining fitness.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see results, you have to stress your muscles, thus change your routine at some period of time. Normally that should be 4-6 weeks. If you do not shock the muscles, do not expect them to shock you. Try implementing different moves in your routine as well as different rep ranges. Instead of doing 3x15, try 5x8 with more weight and change the exercises or at least the order in which you execute them.

If you want to see your abdominal muscles peaking, you must have a significantly low body fat percentage. This is achieved through incorporating a clean diet, regular exercise, some cardio and as well training the inner muscles of the abdominal wall. If you train them first, this will make sure your stomach doesn't stick out like the one of a pregnant woman. Make sure you have good form and squeeze.

Comment: Thanks for your answer brickyyyy! I have my stomach sticking out like the one of a pregnant woman and I don't know why >_> I will try to train my inner muscles now

Comment: _"If you train them first, this will make sure your stomach doesn't stick out like the one of a pregnant woman."_ - I don't quite get how training abs **first** will insure they "don't stick out".